# how to use SupportsCredentials in asp.net web api 1.x?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, cors

everybody. My English is poor. I hope the predecessors can understand.
  I'm having a problem developing today: The technology stack is angular 6.x and Web API 1.x. I used Withcredentials = true in the angular interceptor. As shown in the following code:

```
intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    req = req.clone({
      withCredentials: true,
      url: AppIdConfig.serverUrl + req.url,
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    })
    });
    // ... other code
 }
```

For Cros, my C # code is as follows:

```
 protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        bool isCorsRequest = request.Headers.Contains(Origin);
        bool isPreflightRequest = request.Method == HttpMethod.Options;
        if (isCorsRequest)
        {
            if (isPreflightRequest)
            {
                return Task.Factory.StartNew<HttpResponseMessage>(() =>
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                    response.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowOrigin, request.Headers.GetValues(Origin).First());

                    string accessControlRequestMethod = request.Headers.GetValues(AccessControlRequestMethod).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (accessControlRequestMethod != null)
                    {
                        response.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowMethods, accessControlRequestMethod);
                    }

                    string requestedHeaders = string.Join(", ", request.Headers.GetValues(AccessControlRequestHeaders));
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestedHeaders))
                    {
                        response.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowHeaders, requestedHeaders);
                    }

                    return response;
                }, cancellationToken);
            }
            else
            {
                return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>(t =>
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage resp = t.Result;
                    resp.Headers.Add(AccessControlAllowOrigin, request.Headers.GetValues(Origin).First());
                    return resp;
                });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

[image]
Hope to get your help thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize a CORS policy in your ASP.NET Web API project.
It allows you to accept or reject (depends on your policy) the request from your client.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

This link may help you ;)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: It is web api1.x 。Answer of  @RSadocchi is ok。for example:response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

Answer (score 0):

try to add the key Access-Option-Allow-Credentials: true to HttpHeaders

Comment: What do you mean by that：response.Headers.Add("Access-Option-Allow-Credentials", "true"); it not work...

Comment: change "Access-Option-Allow-Credentials" to "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" .Thank you !